# Retrieve MongoDB result outside callback function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get the document retrieved by MongoClient findOne method (in r parameter) outside the scope of callback function. How can i achieve that?

Maybe my approach to the usage of MongoDB driver for Node.js is not appropiate.

```
function loadUser(name) {
    var result = {};

    function connection(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);

        function callback(err, r) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            db.close();
            result = r; // This does not work
        }
        db.collection('users').findOne({'user.name':name}, callback);
    }
    MongoClient.connect(url, connection);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it, result will not be the correct object because it's returned before MongoDB can find it and the value assigned.

You should do something like:

```
function loadUser(name, cb) {

    function connection(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);

        function callback(err, r) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            db.close();
            cb(err, r) // user
        }
        db.collection('users').findOne({'user.name':name}, callback);
    }
    MongoClient.connect(url, connection);
    return;
}
```

And the usage of loadUser would be:

```
loadUser("example", function(err, user){
   console.log(user);
   //Now do what you need with user
});
```

Also notice that if you are always searching for users, it would be better to just open the connection once, and close it once application is terminated.

Comment: Thanks! I come to the same conclusion! Now i am completely sure that this is the right way to maintain the code that retrieve r isolated of the code that uses it.

Comment: @andresk i got error for this db.collection is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Your 'result' variable lives in the scope of the loadUser function.  The interaction with MongoDB will be asynchronous, so by the time your callback fires, the loadUser function will have finished and the result variable will no longer exist.

You could simply move the result variable to the global scope.  You will probably want to restructure your code a little too though, so that the callback notifies whatever is waiting for the 'result' to return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to process asynchronous tasks, which makes data flow more maintainable especially if you have a lot of conditional tasks to perform :

```
"use strict";

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

// connect to database
var db = MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, dbs) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    db = dbs;
    //get user when connected
    myEmitter.emit('getUser');
});

// getUser event
myEmitter.on('getUser', function() {

    db.collection('users').findOne({ 'user.name': "test" }, function callback(err, r) {
        if (err) {
            myEmitter.emit('processError', err);
        } else {
            myEmitter.emit('processResult', r);
        }
        db.close();
    });

});

// process result event
myEmitter.on('processResult', function(result) {
    //result received, process it here
    console.log("result : " + result);
});

// error event
myEmitter.on('processError', function(err) {
    //an error occured, process the error here
    console.log("error : " + err);
});
```